# why service worker not working after unsubsribe and subscribe again

Tags: push-notification, service-worker

I want to stop push notifications when I log out . Then I unsubscribe. When I am logging back ;then the subscribe service worker again and succeeds, but the push notification is not shown.

```
const createNotificationSubscription = async pushServerPublicKey => {
  //wait for service worker installation to be ready
  const serviceWorker = await navigator.serviceWorker.ready;
  // subscribe and return the subscription
  return await serviceWorker.pushManager.subscribe({
    userVisibleOnly: true,
    applicationServerKey: pushServerPublicKey,
  });
};

const unsubscribeNotification = async () => {
  return navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(reg => {
    reg.pushManager.getSubscription().then(subscription => {
      subscription.unsubscribe();
    });
  });
};
```

I want to show push notifications only when the user is logged in

Comment: Instead of subscribing and unsubscribing, it might be easier to leave the subscription active but not display the notification if the user is not logged in. This check can be either on the server side (or wherever the push notification is being dispatched from), or in the push listener in the service worker, right before you're calling showNotification.

Comment: thank you for your response. but if im login with another account. notification from  previous account will display

Comment: this problem has been solved. unsubscribe must be done on the server and client side. thanks